# Why is the Reversal badge so hard to get?

Tags: discussion, badges, reversal-badge

The description for the reversal badge tells me:

> Provide an answer of +20 score to a question of -5 score. This badge can be awarded multiple times.

Roughly only 300 users have earned the ["Reversal"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/95/reversal) Badge on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) over a period of years. It's hardly ever awarded and is not very common. It is one of the badges that has been awarded the least out of all the badges. I mean look at the gold badge ["Populist"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/62/populist) on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/), it has over 17k users that have it. Why on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/), only 300 on ["Reversal"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/95/reversal)?

What makes this badge so hard to get?

Comment: I'm confused... The description page for the badge states how to get it, can you please explain what part of the description is unclear? https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/41/reversal

Comment: The nature of what it's awarded for make it uncommon.

Comment: It's probably not one of the badges that people attempt to shoot for consciously, but rather one that users generally just end up earning during their normal course of using the site. It's not listed as a badge one can track in their profile. Unsung Hero is another example of this type of badge; no one here on MSE has earned it.

Comment: @Catija I said that in the context of what type of questions would you might be able to earn the badge with.

Comment: That's going to depend on the site. Are you talking about MSE specifically? Your numbers seem to imply that.

Comment: You're talking about how rare the badge is, at 990 awards, but a) that's not *that* rare for a gold badge on a site of this size and b) MSE is *by far* the site with the most awards of *this* badge. [SO has only awarded it 291 times](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/95/reversal), whereas most other badges on SO seem to be roughly two orders of magnitude more common than MSE.

Comment: I still don’t understand the nature of your question. You’d be able to earn this badge with questions which have a net score of -5 or lower. What else are you looking for with “what type of questions might you be able to earn that badge from”? As long as the post is <= -5 and your answe gets >= 20, you get the badge.

Comment: @DanBron i mean the actual type of context that the question has. like the content in it.

Comment: @NathanTuggy I think it's just a badge that's more common on Meta sites because of FR voting... there are over 900 on MSO, too. :) People are more likely to answer (and get a lot of upvotes on) negatively-voted meta posts.

Comment: @itstoobadilostmymainaccount Any content. The rule doesn’t care. Why do you suppose the content of a question should make it easier or harder to post an answer which people agree with?

Comment: @DanBron If it has only been awarded 990 times there is probably a certain catch in a question that makes it get down voted and a certain catch that makes an answer upvoted even with all the bad "energy" within the question already.

Comment: @itstoobadilostmymainaccount I doubt it. I think it’s simply a hard thing to do, and one that won’t occur often on a statistical basis. Which is why it’s a gold badge. Some badge had to be the rarest and/or hardest. Turns out it’s this one.

Comment: @Catija: Sure, it's the nature of any meta (with any of the required tags, really: terrible bug reports can occasionally get really solid explanations, bad FRs often do, dumb discussions do from time to time, and of course lousy support requests are quite frequently answered well), but MSE is the only meta that is standalone.

Comment: Re your edit: on SO it's technically not the rarest, or even the second-rarest, or even the rarest gold badge. [Illuminator (94)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/4370/illuminator) is rarer still, and that's not counting [Sheriff (36, although admittedly this requires winning a mod election)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/3109/sheriff). For that matter, there's [one silver badge that's rarer than Reversal](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1656/research-assistant)

Comment: @NathanTuggy I think we could count the silver badge basically the same as Reversal as it is only 3 less users.

Comment: some think [Reversal badge shouldn't be awarded at all](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/277576/839601), "it just encourages badge hunters to intentionally answer seriously low-quality questions"

Comment: why is this question so downvoted?

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveHedgehog What about a silver badge? that is what the question is asking.

Comment: Please, if you have a new question, [ask a new question](/questions/ask). Your last edit completely invalidated the answer, this is not acceptable behaviour on Stack Exchange.

Comment: @Glorfindel The problem is i got a question ban because people kept marking my questions as duplicates. I also believe a lot of my questions got down voted for no reason. I mean this is a pretty good question and it has 10 downvotes????

Comment: Duplicates won't get you a question ban, but generally speaking your questions lack research. Most of them could be answered by reading the help center and/or the FAQ. I agree that this could be a decent question (the current version, that is) with an answer that is not obvious to non-established users, but by now people here might think "hey, there's that new user with a long name asking a question without research (see the first revision!) again, let's downvote".

Comment: If your questions are consistently being marked as duplicates, and you now have a question ban, perhaps you should take it as an indicator that you need to [search for an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search) to your question before posting.  If it's a common question that other people wonder about, chances are that it's already been asked.

Comment: Stack Exchange has been around for 9 years or so; that means most questions about it have already been asked in one way or another. A new user might be able to pose one or two genuinely new ones, but not *five* in two days. Even the veterans here would have problems to come up with five really new questions.

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain exactly. One of the side effects of a question ban is that the affected user now has ample time to discover the intricacies of the Stack Exchange search function.

Comment: @Glorfindel The first version of this question that i asked was pretty good and it got down voted from the beginning. Before i even got to Revision 2, it already had 5 down votes.

Comment: @Glorfindel how could this post get back into the positive score? its been edited and its still 11 downvotes.

Comment: I'm afraid it can't; you'll have to wait a bit and aak a new question when you can; then, **make it count**. Posting good answers mght help, too. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997/295232

Comment: @Glorfindel I got an answer ban from posting an answer for a community wiki post and it got down voted. i guess community wikis are only supposed to have 1 answer.

Comment: `I mean this is a pretty good question and it has 10 downvotes????` No, it's not a good question by a long shot. It's interesting for you, and you are curious about the badge but its description and the rule on how to earn it is very clear. A better question might have been to ask why it exists in the first place. If a question has earned -5 it is obviously low-quality, possibly off-topic, in which case it should either be closed or deleted. Why reward an answer on an off-topic, LQ question? P.S It has never been earned on EL&U.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I know how the badge is awarded. I clearly say in the question that i know the description for the badge and how to earn the badge.

Comment: So why are you asking? Do you think it's easy to get 20 upvotes for an answer on any of the SE sites? Do you think that level of difficulty is exactly the same if the question is objectively "bad"? Low quality questions usually attract low number of visits too.

Comment: Great, now you add the description. Too late. It was supplied by @Unitato, the description explains *why* it's difficult to earn the  badge.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Because for me it just seems odd that roughly only 300 people have earned the badge on SO out of the millions of users out there.

Comment: Well on meta nearly [1000 users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/41/reversal) have earned it. Bad/poor/low quality questions get answered more frequently here than on the main sites. Look at the users who have earned the badge and then at the number of downvotes the questions  attracted. But you still need to put effort into writing a good answer.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Still very low. 1000 out of millions?

Comment: (counts to ten....)  that's why it's a ***gold*** badge and not bronze.

Comment: @Mari-LouA  "Populist" on Stack Overflow has over 17k. Almost of the other gold badges have way more then Reversal too (in the thousands).

Comment: Out of all the gold badges earned on Meta, it's the easiest and the one that has been awarded most. And this is thanks to the many low quality questions that are posted on meta daily. https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges?tab=General&filter=gold This will be last comment. I hope you now understand how to get the reversal badge and why it is difficult to earn it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The description for the reversal badge tells me:

> Provide an answer of +20 score to a question of -5 score. This badge can be awarded multiple times.

Now, most questions with a score of -5 or below have that score for a very valid reason (on non-meta sites), they are of low quality, show no effort, or is a broad and/or opinionated question. A good majority of these downvoted questions are also good candidates for closure. As such, many of these questions get closed, preventing people from answering them. Even if you manage to stumble across the question before it got closed, adding an answer would only result in you getting downvotes for encouraging answers to a poorly thought question.

Another possible criteria could be popularity. Questions that recieve lots of downvotes are hidden from the front page, meaning that it will recieve fewer views, and less chance of your answer being seen.

It takes an exceptional skill to provide a useful answer to a question that attracts non-useful answers. It also takes incredible luck to have enough eyes on a low quality post to actually get 20 upvotes (assuming you dont get downvoted at all) on such a post.

---

This situation is, of course, different on Meta as votes also indicate disagreement along with the reasons on other sites. An idea can be unpopular, but still worthy of a great answer to explain why such said idea is a bad idea. That's why getting the Reversal badge would be considerably easier on Meta.

Comment: @itstoobadilostmymainaccount this answer has not yet earned the reversal badge. Why? Ask yourself that. This answer has nothing at all to do with your question earning downvotes, but its upvotes does prevent you from deleting your own post.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I guarantee that by the end of the week Unitato will of earned reversal.